# Is the function $\sin(\lvert x\rvert)$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, derivatives

It is readily shown that the function $\sin(\lvert x\rvert)$  is differentiable when $x\ne 0$.

What I know is that $\lvert x\rvert$ is not differentable at $x=0$. But does $\sin(|x|)$ also follow the same rule?

I believe that it is also not differentiable but why?

Comment: When $x\ne 0$, everything is fine, $|x|$ is also differentiable at any $x\ne 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not at 0.

$x\to 0^+$ 1, $x\to 0^-$ -1

Answer (score 7):

We use the fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.
$$
Then, for $h>0$, we have that
$$
\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{\sin(|h|)-\sin(0)}{h}=\frac{\sin h}{h}\to 1,
$$
while for $h<0$, we have that
$$
\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{\sin(|h|)-\sin(0)}{h}=\frac{-\sin h}{h}\to -1.
$$
Hence $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

**Note.** Nevertheless, the function $\dfrac{\sin \lvert x\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert}$ is differentiable everywhere. In fact, it $C^\infty$!

Comment: And in fact, $\frac{\sin|x|}{|x|} = \frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$ \sin(|x|) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l} \sin(x) & \text{if } x >0 \\ \sin(-x) & \text{if } x <0 \end{array}\right.$$

So clearly this function is differentiable for $x \in (-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of intuition (although you should be careful, as this is *not* a proof), you can note that, for small values of $x$, $\sin(x) \sim x$. So in particular, for small values of $x$ (in which case $|x|$ is also small), we would have that
$$
\sin|x| \sim |x|
$$
and that latter function, as you know, is not differentiable. So (roughly) you should not expect $\sin|x|$ to be either.

Now, in terms of *proving* this, the other answers give you the right method.

Answer (score 0):

Near $x=0$, $sin(x)=x+\bigcirc(x^3)$ so $sin(|x|)=|x|+\bigcirc(x^3)$ giving

$$
\sin(|x|)\prime=|x|\prime+\bigcirc(x^2)
$$

Obviously $|x|\prime$ has a jump from $-1$ to $+1$, whereas the error term is continuous.
It follows $\sin(|x|)\prime$ is a sum of a continuous plus a discontinuous function, and hence discontinuous at $0$.